# MVC: Dynamic forms, based on XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm struggling a bit with a dynamic form I'm trying to create in ASP.NET MVC.

I have an XML that defines a form like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ContentType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Fields>
    <ContentField>
      <Name>Url</Name>
      <Value>Home</Value>
    </ContentField>
    <ContentField>
      <Name>Value</Name>
      <Value>Sample value</Value>
    </ContentField>
  </Fields>
</ContentType>
```

Now, I've managed to create a form in MVC using the following syntax:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Content", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
    <br />
    foreach (var field in Model.Fields)
    {
        @Html.Label(field.Name, field.Name)
        @Html.TextBox(field.Name, field.Value)
        <br /><br />
    }

    <input type="submit" name="Save" value="Save" />
}
```

So, this does generate all the required fields, but the problem arises now in the POST of the controller, how could I assign the values of the dynamic generated fields to the correct properties of my model?

Kind regards,

Comment: You might want to consider a custom model binder, see this post for details: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/605595/ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-Model-Binder

Comment: Seems like that's the thing that I need. I'll keep you posted if it's working.

Comment: Thanks, it was exactely what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an index to access the data in your model

```
for (int i = 1; i <= Model.Fields.Length; i++)
{
    @Html.LableFor(model => model.Fields[i].Value, model.Fields[i].Name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Fields[i].Value)
    <br /><br />
}
```

You should be able to make a method marked with Post using the same model.